# Is there a total cost of ownership calculator for cars that will give me electric vehicle options?

Tags: electric-vehicles

I recently replaced a 20-year-old ICE vehicle in need of significant repairs with a five-year-old ICE vehicle. We had hoped that we could buy an EV this time around, but models that meet our needs are only available as new cars, the cost of which we couldn't justify. However, in my search for suitable EVs I was having trouble making a good comparison between the cost of a used ICEV (cheaper up-front but higher operating and maintenance costs) vs a new EV (higher up-front but lower operating and maintenance costs).

**Is there a calculator or tool where I could input the cost and fuel efficiency of a used car I'm considering purchasing outright, and be presented with electric vehicle choices that would have a lower total cost of ownership?**

- I would NOT consider financing a used ICEV, but given the higher cost of an EV and the available tax incentives, I would consider financing a new EV.
- To be useful, any tool should allow me to input:

  - Down payment budget
  - Monthly payment budget
  - My electric rate
  - Local gasoline prices
- I will not buy any car that I wouldn't expect to own for at least 10 years.

I am aware of the [Alternative Fuels Data Center Calculator](https://afdc.energy.gov/calc/) from the U.S. Department of Energy, but this only allows me to compare specific vehicles (so I'd have to know my available EV options up front) and makes a number of assumptions about costs and financing that users can't edit. I'm hoping for a more full-featured calculator.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is, but unfortunately the only calculator I know, which allows determining both the climate impact and the total cost of ownership at the same time, is only available in the Finnish language.

There are few options. You could try using it in Finnish by typing the unknown words to Google Translate to see what they mean if not self-evident immediately.

Or you could click "Lähetä palautetta" (Send feedback) which allows sending mail to the authors at palaute@autokalkulaattori.fi. If you write your feedback in English and request an English language version of the calculator, I'm sure they understand your feedback.

The calculator is available at https://www.ilmastopaneeli.fi/autokalkulaattori/

There seems to be basic financing support, i.e. taking into account the time value of money for bound capital. You can access it in settings ("Asetukset").